# Face Recognition app

Tags: android, security, face-recognition

I am trying to make an app which will trigger live face recognition when someone unlocks the phone and click a photo of the user if it is not the owner but i can't find any suitable API's for it

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: Can you please explain how it is working? i'm not able add this face recognition into my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a normal face detection or face recognition API, make sure the APP can send a url with the content on it (image) to the following API.

You will need to subscribe to the API they offer 100 monthly free requests, give it a try:

API Subscribe / Documentation
https://market.mashape.com/zyanyatech1/face-recognition

The request is as follows:

```
# These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/python
response = unirest.post("https://zyanyatech1-face-recognition-v1.p.mashape.com/facebox/check",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "{subscription_key}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  params=("{\"url\":\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/The_Fabs.JPG\"}")
)
```

The response will be:

```
 {
  "success": true,
  "facesCount": 4,
  "faces": [
    {
      "rect": {
        "top": 737,
        "left": 117,
        "width": 223,
        "height": 223
      },
      "matched": false
    },
    {
      "rect": {
        "top": 171,
        "left": 735,
        "width": 268,
        "height": 268
      },
      "matched": false
    },
    {
      "rect": {
        "top": 762,
        "left": 687,
        "width": 223,
        "height": 223
      },
      "matched": false
    },
    {
      "rect": {
        "top": 134,
        "left": -44,
        "width": 356,
        "height": 321
      },
      "matched": false
    }
  ]
}
```